# Unique ID number in static method through concurrency JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I want to get unique ID from my domain object (table) ID each time a method is called. So that ID's do not repeat. I have a function that returns unique ID.

```
public static Long generateID (Short company)
        throws Exception
{
    IDDAO iDDAO = SpringApplicationContext.getBean (IDDAO.class);
    ID iD = iDDAO.findByNaturalKey (new IDNatKey (company);

    if (iD != null)
    {
        // Check if ID has reached limit, then reset the ID to the first ID
        if (iD.getLatestIDno ().longValue () == iD.getLastIDno ().longValue ())
        {
            iD.setLatestIDno (iD.getFrstIDno ());
        }

        // Get next ID
        iD.setLatestIDno (iD.getLatestIDno () + 1);
        // update database with latest id
        iDDAO.update (iD);

        return iD.getLatestIDno ();
    }
}
```

The issue is that if access the application from two machines and press button from UI to generate ID exactly at the same time, there are sometimes duplicate IDs returned from this method

e.g.

```
Long ID = TestClass.generateID (123);
```

This gives me duplicate sometimes.

I made the method like this

```
public static synchronized Long generateID (Short company)
        throws Exception
```

so that only one thread can go in this function at a time, but the duplicate issue is still there.

I do not want to use database sequences as I do not want gaps in the ID sequences if the transaction rolls back, in that case sequence will be incremented still, which I do not want.Gaps at the middle are OK but not at end. E.g we have 1, 2 and 3 as IDs and 2 rolls back, that is OK. But if 3 rolls back, we should get 3 again when another user comes, in case of sequence, it will give 4

Please help me tell what I am doing incorrect ? static synchronized will still cause other threads to go inside this function at same time ? I have many other static (but not synchronized) functions in the class. Will this cause issue with them too if I make it static synchronized ?

Thanks

Aiden

Comment: `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet`. Done.

Comment: Where to use it in my code ? Also how would we retain the logic of resetting ID number with that ?

Comment: if you are resetting your Id - then  when the time comes for the reset, you will be getting duplicates. Isn't this going to be a problem, anyway?

Comment: Not answering the question, but this seems a lot of work to avoid gaps in your IDs. What's the problem with gaps?

Comment: Why not assign the "no-gaps-IDs" after transactions finish, and use the automatically-generated but possibly-gappy IDs for all the actual work?

Comment: Not getting gap is actually requirement. E.g. Ticket number.. We cannot have gaps in ticket number. It has to be assigned to someone. @Plirkee That is OK. The upper limit is around 1 or 2 billion. and it will take a long time to achieve that,

Comment: @tucuxi Sorry I didn't catch that. Does it mean that we first commit transaction then use the ID ? But what if transaction rolls back ?

Comment: I cannot use AtomicInteger as I have JAVA 6 version :(

Comment: @Aiden atomic Integer  and atomic Long are available from java 1.5. Also I am not shure that you could avoid gaps  - consider the scenario when there are 3 UI requests for id - then 1,2,3 are returned. after that the second UI rolls back but the other two keep the numbers so you have 1,3 what are you going to return to the forth one ?

Comment: @Plirkee Thank you for your reply. The gap in the middle are OK but not at the END. e.g. if 3 rolls back, the next time ID should be given as 3 by the code, not 4 (in case of using sequence). I thought of decreasing sequence by 1 each time transaction rolls back but the issue is how will we know that   generateID () function caused it, other errors in codes can also cause transaction to roll back. Can we use atomic Long ? But question remains. WHY synchronized is not working here.

Comment: @Boris the Spider Can you please edit me code to tell me how to use AtomicLong in my code ?

Comment: Simple; you just need to plug it into your transactions. Should be a trivial task if using JTA (you _are_ using JTA right...). Operations on `AtomicXXX` are guaranteed atomic and visible, so when the transaction rolls back simply roll back the assignment. Note that a gap `1 .. 3` is conceptually no different to a gap `1 2 .. 4` - I don't see what you mean by "end" as if requests come in constantly and always overlap there **is no end**...

Comment: @Boris the Spider Like this ?      AtomicLong al= new AtomicLong(iD.getLatestIDno ().longValue ());.......iD.setLatestIDno (al.incrementAndGet ());

Comment: I doubt that that random code block does anything useful...

Comment: So mean to say, the current method I wrote.. I don't need to add AtomicLong in that ? It will be added somewhere else in transactional code ? Or can we edit the method to make it use your AtomicLong ?

Comment: @Boris the Spider could you tell why adding "sychronized" still gives me duplicates. Shouldn't it make it concurrent ?

Comment: `synchronized` makes things ... _synchronous_. Not concurrent. There could by any number of reasons why sticking `synchronized` into code at random does not make code behave in the desired way; without line by line code review of the entire workflow it is impossible to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep 2 unique IDs:

- a db-provided, internal transaction ID, created by an autoincrement every time a new transaction is built. Gaps may appear if transactions are rolled back.
- a pretty, gap-less "ticket ID", assigned only once the transaction commits successfully.

Assign both from the DB - it is best to keep all shared state there, as the DB will guarantee ACID, while Java concurrency is far trickier to get right.

Comment: How will it ensure that IDs are not duplicated ? Sorry can you please give example ?

Comment: Ticket IDs will be generated *only* once the transaction has committed and cannot be rolled back. Transactions may fail to complete, which would lead to gaps, but ticket ID cannot fail, thus no gaps or dupes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use java.util.UUID. it will generate a universal uniqueId.

Comment: Note that this can work less well if you need many _per millisecond_.

Comment: But not in sequence ? I need in sequence, without gap, e.g. if transaction rolls back, the new and next ID will start from same place where it rolled back to.

Answer (score 0):

In that case I think you try the below :

```
synchronized(this){if (iD != null)
{
    // Check if ID has reached limit, then reset the ID to the first ID
    if (iD.getLatestIDno ().longValue () == iD.getLastIDno ().longValue ())
    {
        iD.setLatestIDno (iD.getFrstIDno ());
    }

    // Get next ID
    iD.setLatestIDno (iD.getLatestIDno () + 1);
    // update database with latest id
    iDDAO.update (iD);

    return iD.getLatestIDno ();
}}
```

Comment: But the method in helper class is already Static. Will it be like     public static generateID ()......{ synchronized(this) if(id!=null).....}. Shall I remove synchronized keyword ?

Comment: The compiler says "Cannot use this in a static context". The method is static